# Storing user's avatar upon registration

Tags: django, post, django-forms, django-signals, user-registration

I have an extended UserProfile for registering new users. My user_created function connects to signals sent upon registering basic User instance and creates new UserProfile with extended fields from my form. Here's the code :

```
from registration.signals import user_registered
from accounts.forms import ExtendedRegistrationForm
import accounts
from accounts.models import UserProfile

def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    form = ExtendedRegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    data = UserProfile(user=user)
    data.is_active = False
    data.first_name = form.data['first_name']
    data.last_name = form.data['last_name']
    data.pid = form.data['pid']
    data.image = form.data['image']
    data.street = form.data['street']
    data.number = form.data['number']
    data.code = form.data['code']
    data.city = form.data['city']
    data.save()

user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

Problem is that on this form I have an image field for avatar. As you can see from the code, I'm getting data from form's data list. But apparently imageField does not send it's data with POST request(as I'm getting **`MultiValueDictKeyError at /user/register/`**, `Key 'image' not found in <QueryDict...`) so I can't get it from data[] .

[alt text http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/3839/61289917.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/3839/61289917.png)
If the usual variables are inside 'data', where should I look for files ? Or is the problem more complicated ? Strange thing is that my form doesn't have attribute cleaned_data... I was using dmitko's method here : http://dmitko.ru/?p=546&lang=en . My :
forms : http://paste.pocoo.org/show/230754/
models : http://paste.pocoo.org/show/230755/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should be validating the form before using it, which will create the "cleaned_data" attribute you're used to.** Just check form.is_valid() and the "cleaned_data" attribute will be available, and should contain the file.

The form's "data" attribute is going to be whatever you passed in as its first initalization argument (in this case, request.POST), and files are stored separately in the "files" attribute (whatever you pass in as the second argument, in this case, request.FILES). You don't want to be accessing the form's "data" or "files" attributes directly, as, if you do, you're just reading data straight from the request and not getting any benefit from using forms.

Comment: damn you're right. Tally forget about validating it. Will check that in a second.

Comment: unfortunatelly, when I check the validity of form, it is not passed. I'm not sure why this is happening since fields seem to pass proper data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `<form enctype="...">` attribute is set to `multipart/form-data` ? Otherwise the browser is not able to upload the file data.

Comment: yes, I'm sure : <form action="." method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">