# Django ImageField Upload

Tags: django-models

I am trying to use Django ImageField to allow a user to upload a profile picture. However, after browsing for the image, when I attempt to update the profile, the picture upload changes from the file name to "No file selected" and I receive "This file is required" error.
If it helps, I was following along with [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLRxkStiaUg). I do understand that he uses two character fields, but I was attempting to change it to handle FileFields. From other questions such as [this one on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129509/storing-users-avatar-upon-registration), I know that the form requires a request.FILES as well.

Here is my **Views.py**.

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('profile.html', args)
```

Additionally, I have these two lines in my settings.

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'userprofile.UserProfile'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'E:\Pictures\django_stuff'
```

Let me know if there is anything else that is required.

As requested by Erny

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from models import UserProfile

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile 
        fields = ('logo', 'description')
```

**Models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos')
    description = models.TextField()

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Comment: Can you provide the source code for UserProfileForm?

Comment: SOLVED, template for uploading was incorrect.